# php regex ignoring size from image url

Tags: php, regex

How can I with regex in PHP make this

```
http://www.domain.com/path/to/image/ipsum_image.jpg
```

Match this and ignore the size part

```
http://www.domain.com/path/to/image/ipsum_image-300x200.jpg
```

Keep in mind that 300x200 can be anything, from 4charsx4chars to 1charx1char

Comment: what are you expecting to get? make it clearer, what have you tried?

Comment: can the image type be png or gif too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$subject = 'http://www.domain.com/path/to/image/ipsum_image-300x200.jpg';
$result = preg_replace('&(-[0-9]{1,4}x[0-9]{1,4})&is', '', $subject); 
echo $result;
```

Comment: `s` is a meaningless pattern modifier because there are no dots in your pattern representing "any character".

Answer (score 0):

```
$str= "http://www.domain.com/path/to/image/ipsum_image-300x200.jpg";
$regex= '/(\d{1,4})x(\d{1,4}).jpg$/i';
preg_match($regex, $str, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);
print_r($match);
```