# Java Regex - Ignoring size string in image url

Tags: java, regex, imageurl

I'm trying to remove the size specifications from image URL strings but I can't seem to find a solution. I don't much about regex so I tried `[0-9x]` but it only removed all numbers in the url rather than just the dimension substring. I only want to get rid of the parts such as `110x61`.

I want to convert my strings from this:

```
http://techdissected.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/google-fiber-rabbit-11-110x61.jpg?6da9e4

http://techdissected.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Nixeus-Headphones-Featured-Image-110x41.jpg?6da9e4

http://techdissected.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Ampedlogo_rac15a_featured-110x94.jpg?6da9e4
```

to this:

```
http://techdissected.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/google-fiber-rabbit-11.jpg?6da9e4

http://techdissected.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Nixeus-Headphones-Featured-Image.jpg?6da9e4

http://techdissected.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Ampedlogo_rac15a_featured.jpg?6da9e4
```

I'm using [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) for testing the patterns but none of what I've come up with works...
What regular expression would solve my issue? Any help would be appreciated. Extra points for removing the trailing `?6da9e4`

I found an interesting solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11479411/php-regex-ignoring-size-from-image-url) but it doesn't seem to work in Java.

Comment: Is the hyphen always before the substring? i.e `-110x61` ?

Comment: see the [demo](http://www.regexr.com/39iqt)

Comment: @hwnd Yes, there is always a hyphen before the substring.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox Thanks, that seems to work great and that website is very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex  `-\d{1,4}x\d{1,4}`

which breaks down to:

```
- : the literal '-', followed by
\d{1,4}: any numeric character, one to four times, followed by
x : the literal 'x', followed by
\d{1,4}: any numeric character, one to four times
```

will work for you in Java

```
String input = "http://techdissected.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Nixeus-Headphones-Featured-Image-110x41.jpg?6da9e4";  
input = input.replaceAll("-\\d{1,4}x\\d{1,4}", "");
System.out.println(input); 
//prints: http://techdissected.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Nixeus-Headphones-Featured-Image.jpg?6da9e4
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly for me!

Is there a way to remove the trailing "?6da9e4" as part of this regex? Someone suggested I use "|\\?.*" at the end of the regex to fix this but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This regex works:

```
String url = "http://techdissected.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/google-fiber-rabbit-11-110x61.jpg?6da9e4";

String newUrl = url.replaceAll("-[0-9]+x[0-9]+", "");

System.out.println(newUrl);
```

Output:

```
"http://techdissected.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/google-fiber-rabbit-11.jpg?6da9e4"
```

If you want to keep the hyphen here `-110x61` use `url.replaceAll("[0-9]+x[0-9]+", "");`

Answer (score 1):

If the hyphen (`-`) is always constant before the dimensions, you could use the following.

```
url = url.replaceAll("-\\d+x\\d+", "");
// http://techdissected.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/google-fiber-rabbit-11.jpg?6da9e4
```

To remove both the dimension and the trailing query:

```
url = url.replaceAll("-\\d+x\\d+|\\?.*", "");
// http://techdissected.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/google-fiber-rabbit-11.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about java, but this might work for any dimensions:

```
/(-\d+x\d+)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

String url = "http://techdissected.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Nixeus-Headphones-Featured-Image-110x41.jpg?6da9e4";

String replaceAll = url.replaceAll("-\\d*x\\d*", "");
System.out.println(replaceAll);